# 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found react native 0.66.3 xcode 15

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried clear podfile.lock && Pods with the command

```
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock build
```

then run

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

but it not working

[image]

**Environment**:

- react-native: 0.66.3
- react: 17.0.2
- node 16.17.0
- xcode: 15